# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition while deleting a topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am writing a integration test case for kafka.I use kafka client version :3.2.0

I get the above error while deleting a topic which in turn leads to the following log which inturn leads to the following log

```
15:48:51,709 [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-44117-ListenerName(PLAINTEXT)-PLAINTEXT-2] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector::pollSelectionKeys()::606 - [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=44117] Connection with /127.0.0.1 (channelId=127.0.0.1:9092-127.0.0.1:54837-32) disconnected
java.io.EOFException
```

please find my code below

```
protected void createTopics(String... topics) {
        for (String topic : topics) {
            while (true) {
                logger.info("Deleting topic {}", topic);
                try {
                    kafkaCluster.deleteTopic(topic);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // ignore
                }
                logger.info("Creating topic {}", topic);
                try {
                    embeddedkafka.createTopic(topic);
                } catch (TopicExistsException tee) {
                    logger.error("Creating topic {} failed. Will delete and try again", topic);
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

And I have create ad delete topic methods in embedded kafka as below:

```
public class EmbeddedKafka {
    public void createTopic(String topic,
                            int partitions,
                            int replication,
                            Properties topicConfig) {
        log.debug("Creating topic { name: {}, partitions: {}, replication: {}, config: {} }",
                topic, partitions, replication, topicConfig);
log.debug("Creating topic { name: {}, partitions: {}, replication: {}, config: {} }",
                topic, partitions, replication, topicConfig);
        final NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic(topic, partitions, (short) replication);

        Map<String,String> configMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
       // configMap.put("bootstrap.servers", brokerList());
        configMap.put(TopicConfig.CLEANUP_POLICY_CONFIG, TopicConfig.CLEANUP_POLICY_COMPACT);
        newTopic.configs(configMap);

        try (final Admin adminClient = createAdminClient()) {
            adminClient.createTopics(Collections.singletonList(newTopic)).all().get();
            adminClient.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //throw new RuntimeException(e);

                log.error("Exception occured while creating topic {}",e);

        }
    }

  public void deleteTopic(String topic, Properties topicConfig) {
        log.debug("Deleting topic { name: {}, config: {} }", topic, topicConfig);
      /*  ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient(
                zookeeperConnect(),
                DEFAULT_ZK_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS,
                DEFAULT_ZK_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS);
        boolean isSecure = false;*/
        /*ZkUtils zkUtils = new ZkUtils(zkClient, new ZkConnection(zookeeperConnect()), isSecure);
        AdminUtils.deleteTopic(zkUtils, topic);*/

        log.debug("Deleting topic { name: {} }", topic);
        try (final Admin adminClient = createAdminClient()) {
            adminClient.deleteTopics(Collections.singletonList(topic)).all().get();
        } catch (final InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            if (!(e.getCause() instanceof UnknownTopicOrPartitionException)) {
                log.error("Exception occured while deleting topic {}",e);
            }
        }
    }
        @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
        public Admin createAdminClient() {
            final Properties adminClientConfig = new Properties();
            adminClientConfig.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokerList());
            final Object listeners = effectiveConfig.get(KafkaConfig.ListenersProp());
            if (listeners != null && listeners.toString().contains("SSL")) {
                adminClientConfig.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, effectiveConfig.get(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG));
                adminClientConfig.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, ((Password) effectiveConfig.get(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG)).value());
                adminClientConfig.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");
            }
            return Admin.create(adminClientConfig);
        }
    }
}
```

on deleting the topics through admin client I am getting the above mentioned error

Comment: That's a debug log, not an error. But yes, if you delete a topic more than once you'll get "unknown topic" message